# Laravel validation not exists in table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-validation

I have two tables, first one is students and second one is lesson_student table. They have m2m relationship between students and lessons tables. I want to check, if student_id exists in students table and not exists in lesson_student table, insert it. I use `exists` to check in students table but i have no idea how to check it is not exists in lesson_student table.

```
public function store(Request $request, Lesson $lesson) {
    $rules = [
        'student_id'    => 'required|exists:students,id'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $lesson->students()->attach($request->student_id);
    return $this->showAll($lesson->students);
}
```

btw i am using laravel 5.6

Comment: Share your DB structure and check only in one table `lesson_student`

Comment: lesson_student table has lesson_id and student_id only, it is pivot table. @C2486

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably you want to use [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) rule like this:

```
$rules = [
   'student_id' => 'required|exists:students,id|unique:lesson_student:student_id'
]
```

**EDIT**

As you updated and explained in comment you want to have unique student_id and lesson_id in `lesson_student` table. Then you can use:

```
$rules = [
    'student_id' => [
       'required',
       'exists:students,id',
        \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('lesson_student', 'student_id')
             ->where('lesson_id', $lesson->id),
     ]
];
```

Comment: student_id is not unique in lesson_student table. lesson_student table has lesson_id and student_id. It is a pivot table. lesson_id and student_id both of them are unique.

Comment: @Nevermore I thought so, but you haven't mentioned this in your question. So where do you have your lesson id when running this request ?

Comment: Nabialek my bad, you are right. I missed it. I updated question with full code. Sorry.